# Android app crashes on tapping on recommended jobs

Tags: bug, android-app

The Stack Exchange Android app crashes when I tap on a job in recommended jobs.

I also did a data reset for the app and reinstalled it but that didn't fix the issue.

Attaching screenshot of the section.
[image: Android app crashing]

Also, all other sections are working fine as expected except the Recommended Jobs, which causes sudden app crash.

- App Version: 1.0.89
- Device Manufacturer: OnePlus
- Device Model: ONEPLUS A3003 (OnePlus 3)
- OS Version: 6.0.1 (26)

**Edit:**

Added the [screen capture](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3y-YevVlnaUdF9vT3M4aFRtdXM/view?usp=drivesdk) of the issue.